# ¿Como consumir y mostrar un servicio web?

Tags: php, javascript, html, php7, mapbox

Se tiene el siguiente servicio web que provee un mapa:
[servicio web que regresa un html](https://platinum.upchiapas.edu.mx/v2/mapageo/load.php?programa=)

se requiere que este mapa sea guardado en una variable, y después mostrar el contenido en la variable, de tal manera que al cargar la pagina, descargue el contenido del servicio, y cuando el usuario de un click, se muestre el mapa, para esto momento ya se tendría en memoria el recurso y evitando cargarlo a la hora.

He usado la siguiente etiqueta que me funciona a la perfección, pero el detalle es que no es buena practica usar iframe o object.

```
  <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="https://platinum.upchiapas.edu.mx/v2/mapageo/load.php?programa=1"></iframe>
```

la idea que se me viene a la mente es un script que haga una peticion http, se guarde la respuesta, y mandar a llamar esta cuando se necesite.

Entonces, que me recomiendan implementar?

Comment: Ummmm hago la descripcion de un pequeño inconveniente... resulta y pasa que ese mapa, al igual que google maps debe tener una forma especifica de integrarse, en cuyo caso, el iframe te funciona correctamente solo porque es una pagina dentro de otra pagina, esta pagina contiene los recursos y scripts necesarios para que se cargue el recurso de manera correcta, pero tienes que considerar el hecho de que por ejemplo, para poder usar google maps en un sitio sin usar iframe necesitas un api key, un script que cargue el mapa y un contenedor del mapa.

Comment: Esto si fuese google maps, pero claramente ese mapa no es google maps, por lo que asumamos que no se requiere una clave... de todas maneras se requeriria un script, un script el cual, si las paginas tienen suficiente seguridad siempre fallara por razones de seguridad y proteccion de recursos, esto se conoce como CORS, y en el caso del iframe funciona porque el script es detectado como del "mismo dominio", pero al poner un recurso directamente sin usar un iframe, dependiendo de que CORS tenga el recurso podras o no cargarlo directamente en la pagina.

Comment: Asi que ahi el dilema... no es tan simple como poner algo que no sea un iframe... y si, yo tambien considero usar a iframe una mala practica... pero en este caso dependeremos siempre de las CORS asociadas al sitio, que bloquearan la posiblidad de renderizar ese mapa en tu sitio o no (depende como configuraron las CORS en el sitio).